# How to see al the commit tree in git bash?

Tags: git, svc

Suppose i have this log in my git bash

```
a16asd
jh243f
h32khk
324io2
k32lji
```

and a16asd is my HEAD. Now when i do

```
git reset --hard jh243f
```

Now i have this log

```
jh243f
h32khk
324io2
k32lji
```

But the commit a16asd is still available to jump to, although not visible when using git log command in the bash. The question is, how to see all the tree, including the commits that are not present in the current tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily visualize 'all of the tree' as you asked and hope to see the commit you just reset, because it's not referred to any more.

You can still see the 'lost' commit `a16asd` with `git reflog`. http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html gives a good overview.

If what you want to do is see all commits in all branches, `git log --all` is what you need.

Comment: actually, git reflog is what i've been looking for, thank you